# How can we make a function do different things based on the nature of its input?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, polymorphism, operator-overloading, dispatch

How do we implement [Predicate Dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_dispatch) in python?

---

Suppose that we have a function named `funky_the_function`.

`funky_the_function` should test its input against criterion and then call some other function based on the result of the test.

Below are some examples of test predicates:

```py
class Predicates: 
    @classmethod
    def is_numeric_string(cls, chs:str) -> bool:
        """
        +-----------------+--------+
        |      INPUT      | OUTPUT |
        +-----------------+--------+
        | "9821"          | True   |
        | "3038739984"    | True   |
        | "0"             | True   |
        | "3.14"          | False  |
        | "orange"        | False  |
        | "kiwi 5 pear 0" | False  |
        +-----------------+--------+
        """
        return all([ch in string.digits for ch in chs])

    @classmethod
    def is_just_one_thing(cls, thing):
        """
        This function returns a boolean (True/False)

        `thing` is defined to just one thing only,
                not many things if str(thing)
                is the same as the concatenation
                of the to-stringed versions
                of all of its elements

                (The whole is the sum of its parts)

        +--------------------------+--------+   
        |          INPUT           | OUTPUT |
        |--------------------------|--------|
        | int(4)                   | True   |
        | str(4)                   | True   |
        | float(9.17)              | True   |
        | str("ABCDE")             | True   |
        | [int(1), str(2), int(3)] | False  |
        | (8, 3)                   | False  |
        | [8]                      | False  |
        | ["A", "B", "C"]          | False  |
        +--------------------------+--------+
        """
        if hasattr(thing, "__iter__"):
            return str(thing) == "".join(str(elem) for elem in thing)
        else:  # thing is not iterable
            return True
```

We have a handful of different versions of a function.

Which version of the function should be called is based on what its inputs are.

How do we implement [Predicate Dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_dispatch) in python?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there were eight different forms of the  `funky_the_function` function.

We could:

> - Write eight different implementations of `funky_the_function`
> - Write eight different test-predicates
> - Write eight different classes.

After that we could write a `funky_the_function` function which:

> 1. tests its input.
> 2. Based on the result of the test, passes the input into one of several different class constructors
> 3. Dispatch using `@singledispatchmethod` from python's `functools` library

```python
from functools import singledispatch

class ArgsOne:
   pass

class ArgsTwo:
   pass  

def funky_the_function(*args):   
    if test_one(args): 
        obj = ArgsOne(args)
        return _funky_the_function(obj)
    elif test_two(args): 
        obj = ArgsTwo(args)
        return _funky_the_function(obj)

@singledispatch
def _funky_the_function():
    pass

@_funky_the_function.register
def _(arg:ArgsOne):
    print("implementation one")
    
@_funky_the_function.register
def _(arg:ArgsTwo):
    print("implementation one")
```